# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0, TensorFlow on Android

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I created my custom model in Keras to recognize happy faces and loaded the model into android and ran into this issue of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at runtime and my app crashed. I have modified the code from here https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/AndroidTensorFlowMachineLearningExample
to suit my model.

Is it the problem with protobuf file creation? I have tested my model and it works well in python. Below are the log file and the source code. Please help with this issue! Thanks!

OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10

TensorFlow installed from: anaconda

TensorFlow version: 1.2.0

Bazel version: N/A

CUDA/cuDNN version: N/A

GPU model and memory: N/A

Exact command to reproduce: N/A

#### Source code / logs

> 01-11 16:21:12.508 18038-18078/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection
> D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xab6c06f0 (ListView) with
> handle 0xab7000d8

> 01-11 16:21:18.135
> 18038-18038/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection
> E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow session:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to
> support Op 'Switch' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU],

> Registered kernels:
> device='GPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
> device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
> device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
> device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
> device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
> device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]

[[Node: bn0/cond/Switch = Switch[T=DT_BOOL](bn0/keras_learning_phase,

> bn0/keras_learning_phase)]] 01-11 16:21:18.135
> 18038-18038/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM 01-11 16:21:18.136
> 18038-18038/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL

> EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection, PID: 18038
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
> at
> java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
> at
> org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.getTensor(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:473)
> at
> org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.readNodeIntoFloatBuffer(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:320)
> at
> org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.readNodeFloat(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:275)
> at
> com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection.TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:161)
> at
> com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection.HappyFaceDetector$2.onPictureTaken(HappyFaceDetector.java:82)
> at
> com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView$CameraListenerMiddleWare.onPictureTaken(CameraView.java:296)
> at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1$2.onPictureTaken(Camera1.java:185)
> at
> android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1118)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)

> 01-11
> 16:21:18.136 18038-18038/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection
> E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService. 01-11
> 16:21:19.470 18038-18038/com.sridhar.deepak.objectdetection I/Process:
> Sending signal. PID: 18038 SIG: 9

TensorFlowImageClassifier file

```
@Override
public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap,int s) {
    // Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

    Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
    // Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
    // on the provided parameters.
    if (s==1) {
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
            final int val = intValues[i];
            floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
        }
    }else {
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
            final int val = intValues[i];
            floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF))/imageStd;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF))/imageStd;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF))/imageStd;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = floatValues[i * 3 + 0] - 1;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = floatValues[i * 3 + 1] - 1;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = floatValues[i * 3 + 2] - 1;

        }
    }
    Trace.endSection();

    // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
    Trace.beginSection("fillNodeFloat");
    inferenceInterface.fillNodeFloat(
            inputName, new int[]{1, inputSize, inputSize, 3}, floatValues);
    Trace.endSection();

    // Run the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("runInference");
    inferenceInterface.runInference(outputNames);
    Trace.endSection();

    // Copy the output Tensor back into the output array.
    Trace.beginSection("readNodeFloat");
    inferenceInterface.readNodeFloat(outputName, outputs);
    Trace.endSection();
```

MainActivity

```
private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 64;
private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
private static final String INPUT_NAME = "input_1";
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "fc/Sigmoid";

private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/happy_model.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE =
        "file:///android_asset/face_label.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the TensorFlowImageClassifier class similar to the tensorflow demo app. The issue is resolved now.